# How to get whether a DB table column is nullable or not nullable in c# EF

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,IS_NULLABLE 
FROM [DB].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test'
```

I want to achieve the above query results in c# Entity Framework. I am able to get the Column Name using

```
typeof(Test).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList<string>();
```

How can I get the values for nullable column?

Comment: I cannot even imagine what `Select(a => a.Name)` method does

Comment: For what it is worth, I would have said to have a look at https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/documentation but the point about nullable is marked as not adressed. Maybe it is an hint that the point is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use EF metadata to get configuration of some entity and it's property. Here is extension method for that (note - no validation for simplicity):

```
public static EdmProperty GetPropertyConfiguration<TEntity>(this DbContext context,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var workspace = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var identity = $"CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.{typeof(TEntity).Name}";
    var entity = workspace.GetItem<EntityType>(identity, DataSpace.SSpace);
    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(selector);

    return entity.Members.OfType<EdmProperty>()
         .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyName);
}    

private static string GetPropertyName<TEntity> (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector)
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
    return expression.Member.Name;
}
```

This method checks storage model space for entity configuration. Then it get's property (column) configuration by property name (again, not validation here). Usage is simple:

```
var property = context.GetPropertyConfiguration<Test>(t => t.Test);
var isNullable = property.Nullable;
```

You can also check other configuration settings here - DefaultValue, MaxLength etc. Of course you can pass property name as string - just create another overload of extension method.

NOTE: If you are using DB first approach, then you need to use another identity for searching item in workspace. It should look like `"{your_model_name}.Store.{entityName}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your entity model should have properties corresponding to non nullable database columns marked with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute`. Thus you could check for the existence of the attribute:

```
var testProp = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Test");
var isNullable = !Attribute.IsDefined(testProp, typeof(RequiredAttribute));
```